# Find angle in this quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, angle, quadrilateral

In the figure below, how can we find $x$ by geometrical arguments and without using sine-cosine formulae or co-ordinate geometry. And if it is not possible solely by geometrical arguments, then why is it not possible?

[Figure](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5jjxuevs6y7nkpx/tri.png?dl=1)

Note: Image not subject to scale. Numbers are for example purpose only, one can have any other numbers as well.

Comment: https://www.duckware.com/tech/worldshardesteasygeometryproblem.html

Comment: Is the answer to your problem equal to $80°$

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct answer is $80^\circ$

I did it by geometrical construction.

Comment: Can you add more details?

Comment: Can I add pictures as solution?